# How to Update the Product Quantity from the DataGridView Displayed Values in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

**Hi Guys. I'm working on a Sales Inventory Project, using C# MS Visual Studio 2013 and MS SQL Server 2014 for Database. Below I'm attaching a 
screenshot of my main POS window with numbers to briefly explain the process.**

[Click here. Main POS window](http://img216.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=57245_03_122_31lo.jpg)

1. This DataGridView shows all the Products with details from the main database...
2. This section shows the SELECTED Products with details..
3. This is the Original Quantity of the selected Products..
4. On this Quantity Textbox we have to enter the no. of quantity of the Product we are going to sale.
5. Now by clicking on Add Button, the selected Product and the new quantity will be added on the below DatagridView.
6. Now This DataGridView table shows all the Products and the quantity to bing sold.

**Now, when We will click on the SAVE Button, I need to perform the following actions.**

1. Insert the records on the Sales Table.
2. Update on the Product table the Product's Quantity, I mean directly from the database to the no. of quantity product being sold.
3. Insert the all the products and details showing on the above datagridview table.. On the SalesDeatils Table.

**And this is my Database Diagram.**
[Click here. Database Diagram](http://img213.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=57245_02_122_687lo.jpg)

**I have successfully done the first part I mean Inserting the records on the Sales Table.
But in the 2nd Part I'm totally freaked out... I'm not getting how I'll perform this task.. Please me to sort out this problem.**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                string ProID = string.Empty;
                ProID = ProID_txt.Text;

                //Insert into Sales
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LookDB.dbo.Sales (InvoiceDate,Discount,VAT,Total) values ('" + this.txt_Date.Text + "','" + Discount_txt.Text + "','" + VAT_txt.Text + "','" + TotalDue_txt.Text + "');";
                cmd.Connection = SQLConnection.con;
                SQLConnection.con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Error_txt.Text = "Save Success";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the total Quantity you could use `Sum(ColumnName)`

Here is an example in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Part WHERE ProdId = 3
```